# Last.fm api and the & character

Tags: javascript, api, last.fm

```
var artist = 'Marina & the Diamonds';
var infourl = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist='+artist+'&api_key=xxx&format=json&callback=?';
```

This is my javascript code, and i use the infourl for a getJson query. But as you can see, the artist variable has a `&` character, and the last.fm api is returning the artist called Marina, not Marina & the Diamonds. Meanwhile, the url seems to be fine:

```
Request URL:http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Marina%20&amp;%20the%20Diamonds&api_key=xxx&format=json&callback=jsonp1301591978245
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL has `&amp;` as encoded `&`.

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Marina%20&amp;%20the%20Diamonds&api_key=xxx&format=json&callback=jsonp1301591978245
```

It should be `%26`.

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Marina%20%26%20the%20Diamonds&api_key=xxx&format=json&callback=jsonp1301591978245
```

Use `encodeURIComponent("Marina & the Diamonds")` to encode the query string parameters.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent("Marina & the Diamonds")` would return `Marina%20%26%20the%20Diamonds`. I guess the code used `encodeURIComponent("Marina &amp; the Diamonds")`

Comment: Yes, the problem was this: $('#artist').html() return &amp; and $('#artist').text() return &